# Push overwrites the content of an array inside an object but not the external data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, database

I have a code that loops through a database response and converts it to Json data, but when I try to add the resulting element in an array, all the previous elements within the array are overwritten with the last one entered, i.e., the data that are overwritten is only inside an array inside the object, not the outer data.

**For example:** (see *costo* and *venta* values)

I have to get

```
[
    {
    "masaTipo_id": 3,
    "masaTipo_nombre": "Panqueque",
    "diet": 1,
    "cuadrada": 1,
    "precioTamano": [
        {
            "tamano_id": 1,
            "tamano": "1/2",
            "tamano_personas": "6 personas",
            "costo": 20,
            "venta": 20
        } (...)
    ]
    },
    {
    "masaTipo_id": 2,
    "masaTipo_nombre": "Hoja",
    "diet": 0,
    "cuadrada": 0,
    "precioTamano": [
        {
            "tamano_id": 1,
            "tamano": "1/2",
            "tamano_personas": "6 personas",
            "costo": 10,
            "venta": 10
        } (...)
    ]
    }
```

But instead I got

```
[
    {
        "masaTipo_id": 3,
        "masaTipo_nombre": "Panqueque",
        "diet": 1,
        "cuadrada": 1,
        "precioTamano": [
            {
                "tamano_id": 1,
                "tamano": "1/2",
                "tamano_personas": "6 personas",
                "costo": 10,
                "venta": 10
            } (...)
    },
    {
        "masaTipo_id": 2,
        "masaTipo_nombre": "Hoja",
        "diet": 0,
        "cuadrada": 0,
        "precioTamano": [
            {
                "tamano_id": 1,
                "tamano": "1/2",
                "tamano_personas": "6 personas",
                "costo": 10,
                "venta": 10
            } (...)
        ]
},
```

And the code is:

```
schemas = [];
schema  = require('./schemas/torta');
for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i+=4){
    schema.masaTipo_id               = rows[i].masaTipo_id;
    schema.masaTipo_nombre           = rows[i].masaTipo_nombre;
    schema.diet                      = rows[i].diet;
    schema.cuadrada                  = rows[i].cuadrada;
    schema.sucursal_id               = rows[i].sucursal_id;
    schema.sucursal_rut              = rows[i].sucursal_rut;
    schema.sucursal_nombre           = rows[i].sucursal_nombre;
    schema.sucursal_direccion        = rows[i].sucursal_direccion;
    schema.sucursal_giro             = rows[i].sucursal_giro;
    schema.sucursal_contactoNombre   = rows[i].sucursal_contactoNombre;
    schema.sucursal_contactoEamail   = rows[i].sucursal_contactoNombre;
    for(let j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        schema.precioTamano[j].tamano_id       = rows[i+j].tamano_id;
        schema.precioTamano[j].tamano          = rows[i+j].tamano;
        schema.precioTamano[j].tamano_personas = rows[i+j].tamano_personas;
        schema.precioTamano[j].costo           = rows[i+j].costo;
        schema.precioTamano[j].venta           = rows[i+j].venta;
    }
    schemas.push(Object.assign({}, schema));
    schema = require('./schemas/torta');
}
```

I've tried other related solutions provided here but without success, and haven't seen this particular case anywhere else (that only the array inside the object is overwritten).
I hope you can help me!
Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two pitfalls in your code, which together lead to the result you see:

1. `Object.assign()` does not make a deep clone, but only a shallow copy. Thus, for properties of a complex type (like your `schema.precioTamano` array), only a reference is copied, ie both objects point to the same (as in identity not as in equality) array.
2. `require` has an internal cache, where the required "things" are stored by key. When the same key is required multiple times, the same "thing" is returned. In your case, I assume `require('./schema/torta')` returns a JSON object. When requiring this object multiple times, you will always get the same (as in identity, not as in equality) object

Taking 1 and 2 together, all elements in the `schemas` array, have their `precioTamano` property pointing to the very same array. Thus, all of them are of course containing the same values (in your case, the values of the last rows you read from the database) and if you change one of them, you are changing all of them.

A simple workaround for your case (as it presumably only deals with JSON objects) could be using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` instead of `Object.assign`

```
schemas.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(schema));
```

as this will create a real deep clone of your schema object.

Comment: Thanks! This have been broking my head since yesterday. My regards.